# How does a QCloseEvent propagate?

Tags: c++, qt, qtwidgets

I have a MainWindow derived from QMainWindow and I re-implemented the closeEvent() handler.

```
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    if (this->okToContinue()) {
        this->writeSettings();
        //event->accept();
        QMainWindow::closeEvent(event); // will work just fine even if this line omitted
    } else {
        event->ignore();
    }
}
```

I've commented out the QMainWindow::closeEvent() to test the app will exit without the event propagating to the base implementation. Weirdly enough, it does exit.

I can just put event->ignore() outside of the if-else statement to prevent exiting but that's not the point.

**Other event handlers such as keyPressEvent() don't work properly without the base implementation in their overrides but the closeEvent() does work without the base implementation.** (Unless, of course, you reimplement everything)

```
void LineEdit::keyPressEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    QLineEdit::keyPressEvent(event); // will not show text in the widget if omitted
}
```

From what I've gathered in the documentation, once an event was handled by a widget, it does not propagate any further, unless explicitly allowed. (*i.e. invoking the base's keyPressEvent() in the implementation of the child's keyPressEvent())*

However a child's closeEvent() will close the application without invoking the base's closeEvent() in it's implementation. Seems like it propagates to somewhere else.

**What makes this happen? Does QCloseEvent propagate to other widgets even after it was already handled?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a nice question. (I never have thought about this.)

After this raised my curiosity, I investigated a bit. That's the nice about OpenSource software – if you are in doubt just have a look into source code. So, I digged a bit on [**woboq.org**](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/):

First I looked for `closeEvent()` in [**qmainwindow.cpp**](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qmainwindow.cpp.html) but I couldn't find it anywhere.

The same in [**qmainwindow.h**](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qmainwindow.cpp.html).

So, I assume `QMainWindow` doesn't override `closeEvent()`.

`QMainWindow` is derived from `QWidget` as easily can be found in the doc. or directly in the source code which I have already at hand:

```
class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QMainWindow : public QWidget
```

Thus, I switched to [**qwidget.h**](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/kernel/qwidget.h.html) which declares

```
 virtual void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event);
```

(currently in [**line 634**](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/kernel/qwidget.h.html#_ZN7QWidget10closeEventEP11QCloseEvent)).

One click again and I approached in [**qwidget.cpp**:9936](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/kernel/qwidget.cpp.html#_ZN7QWidget10closeEventEP11QCloseEvent):

```
void QWidget::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    event->accept();
}
```

Ah, yepp.

This explains nicely why the call of base class method

```
    QMainWindow::closeEvent(event);
```

works as well as a simple call to

```
    event->accept();
```

or even both.

Though, I would prefer the call of the base class event handler.

I consider this as the general useful rule-of-thumb (or idiom?):

- If the behavior of base class shall be *extended* then call the base class event handler in your overridden.
- If the behavior of base class shall be *replaced* then don't call the base class event handler.

Of course, this is a general rule of thumb and should be re-checked depending on the specific event which has to be handled.

(And in case of doubts, there still is [**woboq.org**](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/)...)

Comment: This helped a lot. Thank you